# Does Juno Support Display scaling

Tags: display

may I resize icons and window elements others than just fonts withoutreducing screen resolution

Comment: There's a setting inside system settings that let you choose between high dpi display and normal display. That's the only thing that will do what you want I think..

Comment: where is this option? I can't find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set the scaling factor in the system settings.

Open the settings, click on "Displays" and you'll find the scaling factor at the bottom.[image]

Just a little note, this feature has been added just recently, so you might want to update your system if the option isn't there on your system.